# Matlab GUI stopwatch

Tags: matlab, timer, stopwatch

I am a matlab beginner and struggle with programming my first stopwatch GUI. I want to create 6 different buttons, each containing an independent stopwatch. The idea is that if I press one button, a timer starts that measures how long this button (toogle button) is on and saves this information in a .txt file. I managed to create a function that creates and saves a .txt template. However, I struggle how to implement the stopwatch for each button....
I used the tic and toc function for this, but I get the error that I am not using it correct.

```
function toogle_Tickets_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to toogle_Tickets (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

a = get(hObject,'Value');
start = tic;
stop = toc;
if a == 1
start;

elseif a == 0
stop;

end
```

I know this may seem trivial, however I don't know how to do it better. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is the use of the `tic` and `toc` functions. With `start = tic;` you already start the timer and it runs, so you don't need to (and can't) start it with `start`. Now this timer is called `start` and you can stop it with `elapsedTime = toc(start)`. That way, the elapsed time is saved in the variable `elapsedTime` and you can write it e.g. to a display.

The next problem is that `start` is a local variable, so it is deleted after the function call and you can't access it when calling `toc`. There are two ways around it: the first is to make it a global variable by calling `global start` at the beginning of the function. This will lead to problems when you have multiple instances so this is not the best solution. It is better to add a variable to the handle of the current figure. The `handles` parameter in the callback function is the figure handle. You can add a variable to it by `handles.variable = value`. Then you need to update the handle by `guidata(hObject,handles)`.

Something smaller: According to Mathworks, it is best practice to compare the value of a toggle button to the `Max` and `Min` property of the button, i.e. `get(hObject,'Max')`.

One last detail: it is best practice to give meaningful names to variables, so `a` might not be a good choice. When you call it e.g. `buttonState` it is more clear what is saved in this variable.

All together this gives:

```
function toogle_Tickets_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to toogle_Tickets (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

buttonState = get(hObject,'Value');

if buttonState == get(hObject,'Max')
    handles.start = tic;
    guidata(hObject,handles);
elseif buttonState == get(hObject,'Min')
    elapsedTime = toc(handles.start);
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly! Do you also know how I can save this information to a txt file? I created a txt with the help of a radiobutton (on -> creates txt file with column headers), that has to be pressed when the task starts. How can I save the timing information to the txt file I created previously?